# Android Java more than 1 return statement

Tags: java, android, methods, return

I got this inside a method

```
    View android = inflater.inflate(R.layout.asd_frag, container, false);
    ((TextView) android.findViewById(R.id.textViewAsd01)).setText("asd");
    return android;
    View android02 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.asd02_frag, container, false);
    ((TextView) android.findViewById(R.id.textViewAsd02)).setText("asd02");
    return android02;
```

So the problem is that you cannot return 2 return statements inside a method, does someone know a trick to make this happen.

Comment: There are no tricks. You can't return more than one object from a method. My guess is that your fundamental design is broken. What are you trying to achieve? You'll need to provide more code and a better explanation.

Comment: create a class that can hold multiple Views (or use an existing one, like `List<View>` -- depending on your use case) and return an instance of that

Comment: If you need to return both views, you could return them together as an array or list - but I wonder whether these two things should just be called two separate times in a slightly different method setup.

Comment: Ok so I created an array

        View[] android = new View[6];


        android[0] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.asd_frag, container, false);


        android[0] = inflater.inflate(R.layout.asd_frag, container, false);

but my return doesnt work properly:

return android

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom object which will contain the 2 values or use `Pair.create(a, b)`